# Windows 11 context menu actions for .txt files

Tags: windows-11

For many years (probably since Windows 2000) I can add new actions for `.txt` files using the following registry script

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile\shell\Additional command 1]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile\shell\Additional command 1\command]
@="somepath/someprogram.exe -someoption ""%1"""
```

then in the context menu for `.txt` files in Explorer, there is a new option named *Additional command 1* which performs the indicated command.

But then the computer is migrated to Windows 11, and it does not work anymore, even with Shift or within the *additional options*.

I am aware that the `txtfile` registry entry has been mutated to `txtfilelegacy`, but making this change seems not enough.

Note: this is a default Windows 11 installation, with only UWP Notepad installed. Since this is intended to be projected at clients, solutions like "revert to classical Notepad" won't cut in.

Answer (score 0):

It has been driving me absolutely crazy trying to find this solution. I stumbled upon your post and thought I was saved, then saw no answers. However, through trial and error I eventually found this to work:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt\shell\Additional_Command_1]
```

It's not 100% the same, the command appears a bit lower in the context list vs the old way, but it does work for all txt files. No idea why the old way doesn't work (even with txtfilelegacy). Maddening. Hope this helps though,